# Why is root domain name served by Cloudfront taking me to http://aws.amazon.com/

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have a domain (albunack.net) configured to use Cloudfront (via A record), its **almost** working.

Any request I make such as:

http://albunack.net/style/albunack.css

http://albunack.net/artist/ae65c507-d9a0-4d42-9a6c-2b1f82158b9f

all work fine, and I can see that Cloudfront is seeing them

but simply entering the domain

http://albunack.net

is taking me to

http://aws.amazon.com/ !

I cannot understand why, especially since it was all working great but I had to disable delete the Cloudfront instance (because there was to much data that needed invalidating) and create a new Cloudfront distribtion (which I thought I had done identically)

**Update**

http://albunack.net should take you to http://albunack.net/index.jsp. If you bypass Cloudfront and go directly to the EB server it does do that. Reviewing my CloudFront distrubution I had not set a default root object but setting it to **index.jsp** and redeploying didnt work, nor did setting it to **/index.jsp** so Im out of ideas.

Comment: Looks good from here, http://albunack.net loads your website. NS for albunack.net is served by awsdns (Amazon) DNS servers and I get two A records, both in the Amazon cloud. Maybe it's a DNS caching problem? If you are on Windows, try `ipconfig /flushdns` and be sure to close your browser just in case it caches something.

Comment: @Peterk I am a bit confused because I cleared browsing history in my browser, and I had a problem in another browser, and still had problem when changed configuration to bypass CloudFront. But then later on tried a 3rd browser and that worked ok, cleared all cache in Firefox, plugged CloudFront back in and still working. So in summary not sure sure what occurred here but no longer a problem.

Comment: Ah, the combination of browser and DNS caching is hell that can only be made worse by a proxy server. I'm glad to hear it's working now :)